# How to match a non string in gnu grep

Tags: grep, gnu

I'll use an example to illustrate my problem. Suppose we have the file name 'file.txt' that contains the following string:

> AooYoZooYZoAoooooYZ

I'd like to use grep to find all substrings that begin with 'A' and end with 'YZ' but do not contain 'YZ' in between the 'A' and 'YZ'. The desired output would be:

> AooYoZooYZ
>
> AoooooYZ

My best guess is to do the following:

> $grep -E -o 'A[^(YZ)]*YZ' file.txt

But the output is only:

> AoooooYZ

I'd like the parentheses to hold their meaning for the YZ but I read in the GNU grep manual (http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) that:
"Most meta-characters lose their special meaning inside bracket expressions." I've also tried:

> $grep -E -o 'A.*YZ file.txt

But this outputs the entire line:

> AooYoZooYZoAoooooYZ

Is there a way to override this or another way of solving my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use non-greedy match which can be used in Perl regexp

```
echo 'AooYoZooYZoAoooooYZ' | grep -P -o 'A.*?YZ'
```

However, note that the manual for GNU grep says that -P option is highly experimental.

Comment: That worked. Found a good example explaining non-greedy matching here, as it was new to me: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html